# Normal Control and Inverse Control PID

Tags: pid-controller

I am trying to find out the difference between normal control and inverse control PID. I couldnt find useful information on inverse control. I developed normal PID using `cpp`. Can any body please let me know what exactly is the difference or what is inverse control PID?

Comment: Don't you just invert the output control signal of a normal PID to get the inverted PID?

Comment: I am not sure that is why i asked the question. :)

Comment: as per your comment should i just invert the percentage output of my pid routine?

Comment: I think that depends on your system. You could just use a negative proportional term.

Comment: system is just to control the motor speed 0-100% output of pid will ultimately result in 0-50 hz of drive output frequency for the motor

Answer (score 3):

You want to invert the output (multiply by -1) if the controller output is bipolar. If the output is 0~1 or 0~100% then subtract the output from 1 or 100.

It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The 'direct' or 'inverse' orientation of your PID output depends on what effect the output will have on your error term - does increasing output increase the error, or correct for the error?  Choosing which is application-specific.